# Creating unsafe browser XUL element from Firefox extension gives (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIWebNavigation.sessionHistory]

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to add hidden `browser` element dynamically from Firefox extension but, although it adds successfully, it gives me `Error: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIWebNavigation.sessionHistory]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml ::  :: line 641"  data: no]
Source File: chrome://global/content/bindings/browser.xml
Line: 647`

Code looks like this:

```
let parent = document.querySelector("#browser");
let browser = document.createElement("browser");
browser.style.visibility = "hidden";
parent.appendChild(browser);
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`<browser/>` without `type="content"` or `content-primary` doesn't work very well and shouldn't be used anyway for not trusted. Didn't test the hidden case, but just putting `<browser/>` in the XUL results in an error message that you get and adding the type attribute fixes the problem. So try adding:

```
browser.setAttribute("type", "content");
```

before the appendChild line.

Comment: Unfortunately, canvas.getImageData() doesn't work when called from chrome code if canvas resides in sandboxed document.

Comment: Please create a testcase showing this and post somewhere or file a bug. I don't see why it shouldn't work.